# Monitoring contents of files/directories?

Tags: python, file, cross-platform, filesystems, monitoring

I'm looking for a cross-platform file monitoring python package? I know it is possible to monitor files on windows using pywin32, and there are packages working on Linux/Unix but does anyone know about a cross-platform one?

Comment: Tim Golden has a very simple cross-platform method of polling a directory with os.listdir here:  
http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

Comment: What does "monitor" mean?  Please provide some hint as to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For Unix/Linux based systems, you should use [File Alteration Monitor Python bindings](http://sourceforge.net/projects/python-fam/) to [libfam](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/fam/).

For Windows based systems, you should tie into the Win32 API [`FindFirstChangeNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx) and related functions.

As for a cross platform way, I don't know about a good cross platform way.  I think it would be best to build a module yourself that works on either OS that uses one of the 2 above methods after detecting what OS it is.

Comment: Could you explain how to use the W32 API in an example... because I don't get that...

Answer (score 98):

I'm working on an MIT-licensed library that helps Python
programs monitor file system events as portably as possible.
There are differences that I'm trying to iron out. Highly
alpha version at the moment:

Check it out here:
http://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/

Patches and contributions are welcome.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was looking for a cross platform solution and watchdog is really helpful!

Comment: When will this be available for python3?

Comment: @avendael - Now, apparently. It supports py3k at this point.

Comment: This is definitely the must-be-accepted-answer. Works as charm :) Here is the usage of watchdog: http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html

Comment: Is this till active?

Comment: Just want to say that the project is still actively being developed and looks pretty awesome. Thanks!

Comment: docs are awful, not helping at all ... just saying ... Example: 'patterns argument description: (Read-only) Patterns to allow matching event paths.', ohh it's reallly descriptive

Comment: Last update was three years ago, should I still use this library or go for something like `watchgod`?

Comment: I'm going to make a warning against the library: it currently has an issue, where the watchdog will randomly stop working.

Answer (score 3):

Also check out this option:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog

Was used with a cross-platform app on Windows and OS X.

Comment: Possibly because the author of watchdog posted about it in an answer a year earlier and there's not much in this response? Probably not worth a downvote, but not much worth an upvote either.

Comment: I like it because he said he's used it and it's OK.

Comment: I never get it why an answer got downvoted. Here is the usage of watchdog: http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html

Answer (score 2):

I found this link, which talks about your problem. Although it doesn't really provide s solution/library, I think it will help.
http://www.stepthreeprofit.com/2008/06/cross-platform-monitoring-of-filesystem.html

I don't think there is a cross-platform one yet, so you might want to roll your own.

I am inexperienced in this area so I am not really sure. I hope this helps.

**Note**
I stand corrected, gamin is available on cygwin as Adam Bernier pointed out to me in a comment. You may want to research other options on cygwin (if they exist).

Comment: Seems to be some good feedback for Gamin on Linux.  FWIW, Gamin is listed in cygwin packages:  http://cygwin.com/packages/

Comment: Ah! cygwin! I didn't think of that. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way on Linux is to use inotifywait (given that your kernel is recent enough). You don't need any special bindings, inotifywait can be customized to print output lines on standard output in any way you want. Look and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420143/making-git-auto-commit) for a good example.

Comment: He specifically mentioned cross platform. inotifywait is only for linux