# Back end process in windows

Tags: python, process, backend

I need to run the python program in the backend. To the script I have given one input file and the code is processing that file and creating new output file. Now if I change the input file content I don't want to run the code again. It should run in the back end continously and generate the output file. Please if someone knows the answer for this let me know.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have to set up a so-called FileWatcher, i.e. some mechanism which looks out for changes in a file.

There are several techniques for watching file/directory changes in python. Have a look at this question: [Monitoring contents of files/directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597903/monitoring-files-directories-with-python). Another link is [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html), this is about directory changes but file changes are handled in a similar way. You could also google for "watch file changes python" in order to get a lot of answers :)

Note: If you're programming in windows, you should probably implement your program as windows service, look [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576451-how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-python/) for how to do that.