# How to monitor a directory for changes in Python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitoring files/directories with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597903/monitoring-files-directories-with-python)

I am making an API server that allows hot-deploying of code. And yes, there are dozens of questions about re-importing modules. I just want to monitor a directory, and when a change is detected, perform an action.

```
path_to_monitor="c:\\app\\package"
def action():
    do_something()
dm=dir_monitor(path_to_monitor,action)
dm.start()
```

I need a solution that is mature and cross-platform.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/597903/297323) SO question

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Python thread](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) which uses `os.listdir()` to list files. If you want to monitor other file properties than the file name, `os.stat` might help you.