# How to automatically run a python file when a new file is added to its folder or at a time of day?

Tags: python, file, directory

My python program takes a statistics file and does some stuff on it. It gets a new stats file everyday, so I need the program to automatically run when a new file is added.

Or it could run at the same time every day.

Thanks

Comment: What operating system? The answers to these questions vary quite a bit among them.

Comment: On linux/unix type systems, run a cron job to run your script, and on windows, you might want to use a service

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597903/monitoring-files-directories-with-python

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few possibilities:

Windows:

- Use Task Scheduler to run the script every day at given intervals.
- Use the [watchdog](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) library to monitor a directory for new files and process it as soon a new file is created. This requires your python script to run endless in a loop (or daemonize it)

Linux:

- Use crond to run the script at given intervals
- Use also watchdog or [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify) to monitor a directory for new files ...