# Python script to keep a python file running all the time

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example i want to count number of files in a directory in real time. As python script will be running continuously in background, when i add a file in the directory, value of count variable updates in my script.
So, i need a solution with which pyton script keeps running and updates vcalue in runtime.

Comment: Which operating system?  Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: Other than `while True:`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Monitoring contents of files/directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597903/monitoring-contents-of-files-directories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'task scheduler' if you are using windows, or 'crontab' if you are using linux, those will run the scrip in the background for you.
There are different ways to do the thing that you are asking for.
For example, you can run the script that counts the files, and each time it runs, writes the number of files it found to a txt file somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package called "threading", which runs the code every n seconds(minutes, hours etc.)