# Python: Get the name of a newly created directory?

Tags: python, operating-system

If I create a folder in a root directory, where the folder name is generated by a script.py giving it a name with todays date(YYYY-mm-dd). how do I reference that folder from another script (or the same script at a later stage) in the same directory after it's creation?

Comment: ...You use today's date to reference it?

Comment: Huh? Put the folder name into a variable?

Comment: Are you trying to automatically detect new folders being created? If so, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597903/monitoring-contents-of-files-directories).

Comment: @Rawing "today's date" might change during execution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options:

1. Use today's date to construct the same name in the other script
2. Have the scripts share a common parent environment or calling script that passes the name to both scripts
3. Use [interprocess communication](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html) between the scripts
4. Have the scripts read the filename from a common location (e.g. a file known to both scripts)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Option 1 seems to be the easiest solution for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, but it only works on the same day, and there is a race condition :-)