# How to make the number of buttons update whenever a variable updates?

Tags: python, file, user-interface, button, pysimplegui

I'm creating a GUI and I had an issue. My GUI will work with 3 windows, the first one is going to read the user's ID and see if he have finished the tutorials. If he finished and want to watch any tutorial again, it will open the WINDOW2, if he didn't finish yet it will open the WINDOW3.
In my code, I have for example the tutorials of the section 111, which are inside a folder in my system. To acess and list them I did:

```
path_111 = "D:\\Users\\raulc\\Documents\\AMBIENTES\\videos\\111"
p111 = os.listdir(path_111)
```

But now on PySimpleGUI I don't know how to make the layout have the number of Buttons equal to the number of tutorials. Since `p111` is updated every time a new file is inserted on the folder, the  number of buttons should be updated too, without me. Does anyone knows how to that?

Comment: Variables don't update. OS directories do - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597903/monitoring-contents-of-files-directories

Comment: But every time a file is uploaded on the folder, p111 (which is a list of the files that are in the "111" folder) is going to increase it's size

Comment: Create a window based on the number of files when starting, or Refresh a window based on the number of files as it changed immediately ?

Comment: Create as many buttons as you are likely to need, but hide any that don't have a corresponding file yet. Then unhide them as needed.

Comment: It's a good strategy, but what should I do if the Button name is associeted to the file name.

Comment: `p111` will not update as files are added unless you repeated run `os.listdir` in some loop. Try it. And when you re-run that, you would need to clear all the existing buttons and reload with all new ones (please [edit] your question to show how you draw buttons now)