# How do you get times of files that are added to a folder without knowing which files are actually going into said folder? Python

Tags: python, timestamp, file-handling

Hopefully this clears up the title! All the tutorials and forums I've checked to solve this issue all have the same thing in common, they know which file is going to be placed inside of the folder and they'll set of a variable like: `path = "myfile.txt"`
What if I didn't know the file name until the user places the file into the folder, how would I set up a variable to account for this?

I know to use the `os.path.getctime()` but don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Use [listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) to check what files exist in a folder. You could check before and after the user adds a file.

Comment: It's unclear to me what the specific question is here. Do you want to [monitor files / dirs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/597903/10197418)?