# How to autorun RSpec in textmate

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, textmate

I am building a simple Sinatra app.

I am using Textmate (1.5.11) and have successfully installed RSpec bundle (https://github.com/rspec/rspec-tmbundle)

Currently the RSpec Textmate bundle works fine but I don't like having to manually trigger the execution of all the tests in my spec folder.

I have have guard-rspec already running (with growl notification) but I would like to trigger the Textmate RSpec bundle - it is a nice UI and displays all the test result info in a format I like.

Is there a way to configure Textmate + RSpec bundle to auto run whenever a .rb file is saved?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try Guard http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=guard+rspec

Comment: @iain thanks.  I have have Guard-rspec already running (with growl notification).  Sorry I should have been more specific.  I would like to trigger the Textmate RSpec bundle - it is a nice UI and displays all the test result info in a format I like.

Comment: Ah, ok. Have you seen this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4609137/335847 ? Maybe hooking into the save command will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to 
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec-guard to install Guard

3.6.2 Automated tests with Guard

then you can also add

http://jam.im/blog/2013/02/11/mac-osx-notifications-with-guard/

Mac OSX Notifications With Guard

so you don't have to use growl notification