# source control - establish link between different files

Tags: git, github, version-control, mercurial, synchronization

In source control is it possible to enforce simultaneous updates for multiple files at the same time by establishing some link between them?

e.g.:

File_A shares some settings with File_B, hence source control enforces check out/in both files at the same time?

Comment: Define what you mean by check-in/check-out. I think in svn and git there's no such thing. Are you referring to TFS?

Comment: In Git, when you pull from the repository, _all_ files in that branch will be updated, so this concept may not really be applicable in Git.

Comment: In git, this can be enforced during analogical merge operation

Comment: What is an `"analogical"` merge operation?

Comment: analogical to check-in behavior

Comment: Commits in every system I've seen are multi file operations. Same with Update. If you want to force a user to pass some test in order to commit, a pre-commit hook (hg, and likely something similar in git) could be used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dropbox-style svn/git/mercurial?: auto-commit upon change and auto-checkout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060769/dropbox-style-svn-git-mercurial-auto-commit-upon-change-and-auto-checkout)