# How to setup git on server for auto commit/push?

Tags: php, git, github, joomla, git-commit

I have a sever and there I have Joomla installed and I wanted to setup git for this server. when a file is changed on this joomla setup it should automatically commit/push changes to the github repo.

is it possible with the help of php?
if yes please let me know how?

Answer (score 1):

For auto-commit, you want your system to watch file updates. See [Making git auto-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420143/making-git-auto-commit) for more info.

If you want auto-push after the commit, you might want to look for post-commit git hooks : https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks