# Is it possible to create a git patch on explicit save PHP / WebStorm

Tags: git, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm often need to develop on few PC, but when the change isn't ready to commit - I just create a patch and save it to Dropbox to have an opportunity to finish it from another location.

Is it possible to create a patches on explicit save on PHP / WebStorm?
By the name of current changelist or with some default way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create a new branch and push that branch. Later if you finished your work you squash merge it or merge your commits interactive and merge --ff-only that :-)

Lookup the man pages for `git merge --squash`, `git rebase --interactive` and `git merge --ff-only`.

Comment: Yeah, seems it much better way then patches :)

But the problem still exists, sometimes I just forgot to do a patch, or in the new way - will forgot to commit the code to the new branch

Is there some way to automate it w/o commits spamming?

Comment: If you are on a branch and use something crazy to make [git auto commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/420172/510711), you can squash all those commits later on during rebase --interactive or with a squash merge.