# Is there any way to commit changes in git automatically at specific time

Tags: linux, git, time, repository, commit

I want to know if there is any way to auto-commit changes made in git based on specific time.

Suppose if I set the configuration, it should commit whatever the code present in repository at exactly 12:00 AM every day or at specific time in a day.

From what I found after searching, there is a way to commit on every time we save a file. But not timely auto-commits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making git auto-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420143/making-git-auto-commit)

Comment: I don't need to record all the changes everytime ( which causes more commits ). but all the changes at specific time ( which causes few commits )

Comment: Build a script and start it in crontab is one way.  I do not know if there is a git scheduler...?

Answer (score 2):

As Nic5300 suggested, an easy way to do this is to write a simple script that is called by `cron` at a specific time:

```
auto_commit.sh
=======================================
#!/bin/bash
MESSAGE="Auto-commit: $(date)"
REPO_PATH="/home/user/repo"
git -C "$REPO_PATH" add -A
git -C "$REPO_PATH" commit -m "$MESSAGE"
```

Just update the REPO_PATH and MESSAGE with whatever you'd like. Now, you add the script to your crontab by running `crontab -e`.

To run it every night at midnight, your crontab would look like this:

```
* 0 * * * auto_commit.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Obviously, you'd have to update that path to wherever your script is saved. Just make sure you have `cron` running (depends on what init system you're using), and you should be good to go. Check out https://crontab-generator.org if you want to fiddle more with your crontab.

Answer (score 1):

Your crontab example would start executing the auto_commit.sh script at midnight every minute for 1 hour. To make it run only once every midnight, you need:

```
   0 0 * * * auto_commit.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```