# How to recover a file that was damaged by VSCode?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I am using **Visual Studio Code** in one of my recent projects. Unfortunately, today it hanged too much and every time I select **Reopen** option from the pop-up **VS Code** show when it got hanged.

After 5-6 times hanged within 30 minutes I select **Close** from the pop-up rather than **Reopen**.

After a few moments later I start **VS Code** again, I saw that all of my codes from the file that was open during the last hang was completely removed!!

Does anyone know, is there any way to recover that file?

Comment: I advise using a source code control system to mitigate this in the future.

Comment: I already use GIT in that project. But it does not mean that I will commit my source every second.

I can recover the old code of that file but I can recover what I did in the last few hours!!!

Comment: Might be helpful to the point of not committing every second. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420143/making-git-auto-commit