# Is it possible to set up a git client on an application server to automatically version control and push configuration files to an Azure Repo?

Tags: git, azure, version-control, azure-devops, repository

We have a machine learning and analytics platform which allows the user to build and combine data pipelines, uni/multivariate analyses, and imported python models. These are stored as config files which can be exported as json or text. Instead of forcing users to manually export files and upload/commit to the remote repo, is it possible to install the git client on the server where the application and config files are hosted to automatically upload/commit updated files to the remote repo?

Comment: Hi, Did you get a chance to check out below workarounds, how did it go?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to automatically commit and push file changes to remote repo.

If the application is hosted on linux server, you can use [inotifywait](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools). You might need a [personal access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) to to push to azure repo.

`inotifywait -q -m -e CLOSE_WRITE --format="git commit -m 'auto commit' %w && git push https://PersonalAccessToken@dev.azure.com/path/to/azurerepo --all" <<file>> | bash`

For windows system, you can write a batch file containing the git commands and use scheduled task to run the batch file automatically. Or you can use Directory Monitor as mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420143/making-git-auto-commit). see below example batch file:

```
cd c:\gitRepoDirectory\
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "username"
git add .
git commit -m autocommit
git push https://PersonalAccessToken@dev.azure.com/path/to/azurerepo --all
```

Check out below links for more information:

[Setting-up automatic Git pushing upon file change](http://darencard.net/blog/2017-05-02-auto-git-file/)

[Making git auto-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420143/making-git-auto-commit)